# How to keep a history/records of past calculations in the calculator app in the paper tape?

Tags: macos, applications

On macOS Monterey (12.4), after doing some calculations on the calculator app, quitting the calculator, and then opening the calculator app again. The paper tape feature is cleared and does not have a history of past calculations from the last time the app was opened.

How do you keep a history/records of past calculations in the calculator app in the paper tape?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer here: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/calculator-paper-tape-gets-deleted-after-quitting.1982584/

The persistence of the Paper Tape window's contents depends on a system-wide setting.

The setting is controlled by:
System Preferences > General > checkbox: Close windows when quitting an app

Make sure checkbox is off for calculator tape window to keep history/records of past calculations. (refer to screenshot of checkbox state)[image]